# Filter individual that has two different criteria?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset

TLDR: Need to filter an individual by two different criteria

Basically given the example below I need to know which individual got both cheese and bread and return the rows which are equal to this. In the example these are ablibaba, mary and steve.

Typically multiple filter criteria in dplyr are pretty simple but this is looking across different rows so I'm finding it quite tough. I did come up with a long solution but I'm sure there is a more efficient manner.

I'm dealing with a large dataset so speed is of the essence.

```
set.seed(1111)
df = data.frame(ID = sample(c("bob","steve","mary","alibaba"),20,replace = TRUE))
                
set.seed(1311)                
df$food = sample(c("cheese","bread","olives"),20, replace = TRUE)

# finding which individuals have both cheese and bread
index = df %>% distinct(ID,food, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(food == "cheese" | food == "olives") %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(freq = n()) %>% 
  filter(freq > 1) %>% {as.vector(.$ID)}

# returning the rows for the individuals that have both cheese and bread
df %>% filter(ID %in% index,food == "cheese" | food == "olives")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping by 'ID', `filter` those groups having both 'cheese', 'olives' by wrapping with `all` and at the same time  do an elementwise filter with the second expression (`food %in% c('cheese', 'olives')`)

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     filter(all(c('cheese', 'olives') %in% food), food %in% c('cheese', 'olives'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 13 x 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
#   ID      food  
#   <chr>   <chr> 
# 1 alibaba olives
# 2 steve   olives
# 3 steve   olives
# 4 steve   olives
# 5 alibaba cheese
# 6 steve   olives
# 7 steve   olives
# 8 mary    cheese
# 9 alibaba olives
#10 mary    olives
#11 steve   cheese
#12 alibaba olives
#13 steve   olives
```

---

Or another option that is potentially faster would be to first `filter` and then do a group by and filter those groups having 2 distinct values in 'food'

```
df %>%
     filter(food %in% c('cheese', 'olives')) %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>%
     filter(n_distinct(food) == 2)
```

---

Or another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[, .I[all(c('cheese', 'olives') %in% food) & food %in% c('cheese', 'olives')], ID]$V1
df[i1]
```

Comment: I think it looks good....could you just explain perhaps?

Comment: @Dasr i updated the post.  Hope it helps.  If you can tell me where the issue is, i can help you

Comment: All is ok. I was just trying to understand the first answer you gave. But it's working. Thank you.